# Open date picker on TextField focus event | Material UI Library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use simple date picker as in this example:

https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/#date-pickers

Currently date picker on click/focus selects part of text:

[image]

How to make date-picker widget default on click/focus event (currently user must click on that bottom arrow to activate date picker widget).

[image]

Comment: where you ever able to find this out? Current trying to focus/open dropdown when i use tab key